# Value update is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map

Tags: java, scala, function, class, methods

I am getting error:

> value update is not a member of
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing] for map(i) = function

How would I fix this? Scala code and main task are both below.

```
package main_class

class mainClass {
   def main_method[Type](listInt : List[Int], function: Int => Type) = {
   var map = Map()
      for(i<-listInt){
         map(i) = function
      }
   map
   }
}
```

Task:

In a package named `main_class`, create a class named `mainClass` with a method called `main_method` that:

- takes a type parameter
- as parameters takes a list of `Int` and a function that takes an `Int` and returns the type of the type parameter
- returns a Map of `Int` to the type of the type parameter
- the returned Map contains all the `Int` from the input list as keys and each key maps to the output of the given function when called with `Int` as its argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Map` can be thought of as a specialized collection of 2-tuples. So first create a collection of tuples then apply `.toMap` to it.

```
listInt.map(i => (i, function(i))).toMap
```

Comment: I am returning Map[Nothing, Nothing] instead of Map[Int, function]. How would I solve that?

Comment: The posted code returns `Map[Int,Type]`. If you're getting something different then you haven't applied it correctly. This code is the _entire_ `main_method()` code.